# Zend Doctrine RuntimeReflectionService class does not exist

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I followed instructions in https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/1.0.x/docs/hydrator.md
but instruction `$hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator( $objectManager );` doesn't work :

ReflexionExeption
file : `/Users/joseribeiro/Sites/zendoct2/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php:73`

message : `Class does not exist.`

Controller :

```
namespace Product\Controller;

use DoctrineORMModule\Paginator\Adapter\DoctrinePaginator as DoctrineAdapter;
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as DoctrineHydrator;
...

public function editAction()
{
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');

    $hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator( $objectManager );
    ...
}
```

My module.config.php

```
'doctrine' => array(
  'driver' => array(
     __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => array(
         'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
         'cache' => 'array',
         'paths' => array(__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity')
     ),
     'orm_default' => array(
         'drivers' => array(
              __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
          )
     )
  )
)
```

Error log :

```
[Tue Aug 27 12:56:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Missing argument 2 for DoctrineModule\\Stdlib\\Hydrator\\DoctrineObject::__construct(), called in   .../module/Product/src/Product/Controller/ProductController.php on line 90 and defined in .../vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php on line 71
[Tue Aug 27 12:56:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: targetClass in .../vendor/doctrine/doctrine-module/src/DoctrineModule/Stdlib/Hydrator/DoctrineObject.php on line 76
[Tue Aug 27 12:56:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  class_parents(): object or string expected in /Users/joseribeiro/Sites/zendoct2/vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/RuntimeReflectionService.php on line 40
[Tue Aug 27 12:56:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in .../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php on line 257
[Tue Aug 27 12:56:27 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in .../vendor/doctrine/common/lib/Doctrine/Common/Persistence/Mapping/AbstractClassMetadataFactory.php on line 257
```

I don't understand what is wrong !

Comment: I do change `$hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator( $objectManager );` to `$hydrator = new DoctrineHydrator( $objectManager, "Product\Entity\Product" );` It's not like description. I don't know why !

Comment: Documentation is for 1.0.x branch and you are probably using 0.*. Here's a doc for your version https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineModule/blob/0.7.x-dev/docs/hydrator.md